# What does the "increment" mean in stationary increments

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

i can't understand what does the "increment" mean in stationary increment,does it mean distribution?I just know the "increment" means that the value of something increase,but if i replace "increment" with these sentence.it seems weird

The definition of stationary increment :$X$ has stationary increments if for $s,t \in$ with $s \le t$, the increment $X_t -X_s$ has the same distribution as $X_{t-s}$.

Comment: "Stationary" means "independent of time" in a sense, and increment means...increment, i.e. $X_t-X_s$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson does it mean the distribution between $X_t$ and $X_s$

Comment: It means $X_t-X_s$. The only ambiguity here is how to interpret "stationary", or in what sense $X_t-X_s$ is independent of time.

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing called "distribution between $X_t$ and $X_s$".